# Big O - Time Complexity puzzling for while loops

Tags: while-loop, big-o, time-complexity

As a time complexity example (refreshing my mind) I am attempting to solve find the running time (in terms on n) of the following algorithm:

```
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {      //O(n)
  k = 1;
  for (j=1; j <= i; j++) {    //O(n)
    k = 2*k;
  }
  j = k*k;
  while (j > 1) {             //O(..?)
    j = j / 2;
  }
}
```

I understand the first two for loops combined take O(n^2), however I am a little perplexed at how to find the running time of a while loop.  Although I know the while loop runs twice the first execution, then 4 times, then 6... all multiples of 2.  Would that just make it run O(nlog(n)) times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated division is `log_2(j)` which is the same as `log(j) / log(2)`.  The `log(2)` is constant, so it's just written as `log(j)`.

Because the `O(log(n))` is at the same depth as the `O(n)` loop and the `O(n)` loop dwarfs the `O(log(n))` loop, the two combined takes `O(n)` time.

The final time complexity will be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Excellent, I must have lost myself in the increasing value of j, but never stopped to realize the simplicity of the log_2(j) remaining constant every division.  Thank you!

Comment: The final answer is correct, but it seems to me that the third loop executes O(n) times, not O(log(n)), because initially, k is 2^i, which's log is i.

Answer (score 0):

For each value of i, we execute two loops.

The first one executes i times for each value of i
The third one, j start at 2^i and is divided successfully by 2, so it also executes i times.

in total, we have O(1+2+..+n) ~ O(n(n+1)/2) ~ O(n^2)